# Having trouble running python in cmd.

Tags: python, cmd, notepad++

I am a complete noob when it comes to programming. I just downloaded python and I will be using Notepad ++. I have saved a file to my desktop and the file name is test and changed the extension from .txt to .py

So when I go to Notepad ++ and create a program and save it, I go to the cmd prompt making sure I am in my desktop directory and type the following

python test.py

and it tells me that python is not recognized. Any help to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add python to your environment variables https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables

Comment: And when asking system-level questions like this, always tell us which OS you are using, although in this case we can tell you're using Windows from the problem (every other OS has Python built in).

Comment: I just went to the control panel then clicked system, then clicked advanced system settings then clicked environment variables and added a new system variable by putting in the following 
Variable Name: Python
Variable Value: C:\Python34 
Then I went back into cmd and then tried it again and it still has the same error.

Comment: @Curtass restart your computer

Comment: Restarted my computer and still the same problem

Comment: @Curtass You need to add the python directory to the front of the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

First thing python is indent oriented programing language and it  comes with  its default editor called IDLE. So if you use notepad++ instead of IDLE it might gives you a syntax error. Second thing for executing python file from command prompt,you need to setup environment variable.Please see below link for setting up environment variable.

https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html

You can directly run your program in IDLE without using command prompt. So i would suggest you to use pythons built in editor (IDLE)